# Spring Boot JPA not finding data source

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot application with the following configuration:

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

Main configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mycompany.it")
@Import(DatabaseConfiguration.class)
public class Configuration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
```

Database configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mycompany.it.xp2.integration.workday.dao","com.mycompany.it.xp2.integration.workday.application","com.company.it.xp2.integration.workday.model"})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.company.it.xp2.integration.workday.dao","com.company.it.xp2.integration.workday.model"})
public class DatabaseConfiguration {
```

With DataSource bean declaration:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
        ComboPooledDataSource source = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        source.setDriverClass(driverClass);
        source.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
        source.setUser(jdbcUsername);
        source.setPassword(jdbcPassword);
        source.setInitialPoolSize(initialSize);
        source.setMaxPoolSize(maxActive);
        source.setMinPoolSize(minIdle);
        return source;
    }
```

However when I start up the application I get the following error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at
>   least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations: {}

Here are the related lines from gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-aop'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm'

compile group: "org.springframework.boot", name: "spring-boot-starter-jdbc"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
```

Spring boot version 1.5.3

Comment: can you please post the dependencies for the project and have you added database connector dependencies

Comment: why are you excluding the DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class from the spring auto loader?

Comment: We have a policy of not checking in passwords to source code, and since multiple projects are sharing the same tomcat instance, we can't just use the spring.jdbc.password property in the tomcat environment settings

Answer (score 0):

Check the error log

> 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations

It seems that there is an error when you configured the bean.